# Why is here a gap in-between the last sections?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on the freecodecamp html/css profile page project. Its been pretty fun so far learning and trying to figure this out by myself but I am stuck with this. I have check and tries the solutions on similar questions but they dont seem to work, but anyhoo.

I have a gap between the last two sections on the paged @ive linked below. I have tried setting the padding and margins to zero but it was no use. Can I get a white knight here please!

https://codepen.io/michael-card/pen/PoEwbxP?editors=1100

```
#contact{
  background-color:lightgreen;
  height:100vh;
  text-align:center;

}

#contact h1{
  padding-top:10em;
  font-size:2em;``
  height:100vh;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Set your `#contact h1` margin to zero.

Comment: Thanks I was only thinking about the sections and not the h1! Thanks for taking the time bertdida, your a champ!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the h1 in the contact section has a margin attached to iit - simply putting margin:0 in the styles resolves your problem and allows the sections to butt up against each other with no whitespace I have highlighted where I added the margin: 0.

To resolve similar problems in the future - open your developer console and inspect all the dom elements and that would show you what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will try opening that in the future gavgrif! That's been buggin me all morning.

Comment: Happy to help - if this resolves your issue - please click "accept" so that other devs know the issue has been fixed. With respect to the dev console - I strongly asuggest you keep it open all the time and get in the habit of both inspecting the DOM and also console.logging restults, tests , values etc. It is an invaluable tool for a dev to be able to see the effect of the code and to be able to debug when things go wrong. Thanks and happy coding :)